# How to create a element to set item per page

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I use this [library](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples) to create pagination.
My problem is:

If I want create a component where I can put default value for itemsFor page in pagination, where the user can choice,

Anyone can suggest me some links where I can read some examples?

EDIT:
Here there is one possibility solution:

[image]

I want know If I need create a select or there is a component just created to do that!

Comment: hey am not getting what you trying to do can please give more information so we can help you

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: so you want to use this pagination as a common component

Comment: yeah I use ng-bootstrap and I use pagination to left but I want to use something similar in the rigth part

Comment: you can go with material pagination if you want